# Error while using leavevmode before newline

Tags: line-breaking, warnings

I am using `\newline` but I get some error message and I was suggested on this forum to use `\leavevmode` before `\newline`. It works fine for my code except at few place where I get this error message.

```
 ! Undefined control sequence.
 l.399 \leavevmode
```

How to avoid such warning/error?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `\leavevmode`? Anyways, what are you using `\newline` for?

Comment: I need to add some vertical spacing using newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do *not* use `\newline`. Use instead

```
\smallskip% 1/4 line
\medskip%   1/2 line
\bigskip%    1 line

\vspace{<length>}% a length with any valid unit
```

Comment: I need a linebreak, i think bigskip is not equivalent to newline.

Comment: do you have a tabular cell? Or where do you need `\newline`?

Comment: No, I don't have tabular cell. I need add one vertical spacing within a paragraph.

Comment: then use something like `\\[1cm]` if it must be in the _same_ paragraph. However it makes more sense to use an empty line and then one of the skip commands.